# Is there any reason why /proc/*/cmdline is world-readable?

Tags: linux, permissions, proc

Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet today, but I can't remember or think of any reason why `/proc/PID/cmdline` should be world-readable - after all, `/proc/PID/environ` isn't.

Making it readable only by the user (and maybe the group.  and root, of course) would prevent casual exposure of passwords entered as command-line arguments.

Sure, it would affect **other** users running `ps` and `htop` and the like - but that's a good thing, right? That would be the point of not making it world-readable.

Comment: one thing to note: passwd can easily be hidden in interactive commands. for ex: `some_cmd -p "thepwdhere" ...` can be instead done as : `some_cmd -p "$(cat)" ...`, and enter your password with:  `thepwdhere<Enter><ctrl-d>`. Could come in handy sometimes... (to hide it even in your own history, so that if you show (or copy-paste) it to show to colleagues, it doesn't show the password used, for exemple)

Comment: @OlivierDulac that doesn't actually keep it out of the process's /proc/pid/cmdline.   The shell runs the `cat` command substitution and inserts cat's output into the command line.   Works fine for keeping a password or whatever out of the shell history, but not for stopping it being visible in `ps` or `top` etc.

Comment: @cas Good point (relevant to the question asked), I was principally focusing on the history file

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yep. Though at least for that use, `/proc/cmdline` probably wouldn't need to be readable by anyone else but root.

Comment: Presumably you're implicitly asking why `ps -ef` can return information for other users' command lines too

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I suspect the main, and perhaps only, reason is historical — `/proc/.../cmdline` was initially world-readable, so it remains that way for backwards compatibility. `cmdline` was added in 0.98.6, released on December 2, 1992, with mode 444; the changelog says

```
     - /proc filesystem extensions.  Based on ideas (and some code) by
       Darren Senn, but mostly written by yours truly.  More about that
       later.
```

I don’t know when “later” was; as far as I can tell, Darren Senn’s ideas are lost in the mists of time.

`environ` is an interesting counter-example to the backwards compatibility argument: it started out word-readable, but was made readable only by its owner in 1.1.85. I haven’t found the changelog for that so I don’t know what the reasoning was.

The overall accessibility and visibility of `/proc/${pid}` (including `/proc/${pid}/cmdline`) can be controlled [using `proc`’s `hidepid` mount option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html#DESCRIPTION), which was [added in version 3.3 of the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0499680a42141d86417a8fbaa8c8db806bea1201). The `gid` mount option can be used to give full access to a specific group, *e.g.* so that monitoring processes can still see everything without running as root.

Comment: oh, nice! i wasn't aware of the hidepid mount option.

Comment: Having `/proc/.../environ` locked down is necessary if you're using variables like `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` or `MYSQL_PWD` to simplify access. Not a good idea generally but some people use these variables.

Comment: @doneal24 yes, and the same argument applies to `cmdline` (with the same caveat).

Comment: AIUI, the permissions change on `environ` was done because the info there was never public info on traditional UNIX systems (unlike a process’s command line), so anything relying on it being public was inherently not portable to begin with, and some applications already relied on their environment not being public knowledge for security reasons. Early on, existing parts of the Linux ABI were not as immutable as they are today, and decisions like this were sometimes made to ensure consistency with other platforms when there were such security related considerations.

Comment: @Austin AFAIK the BSDs considered that the environment was public info — at least, BSD `ps` could display it.

Answer (score 23):

The command line of the processes has always been considered public information in Unix and was always available via the [`ps(1)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ps.html) command. The environment of a process, on the contrary, was never such public information.

In the original Unix implementation, `ps` was a setuid executable which was opening `/dev/mem` and extracting all the information directly from the live memory of the kernel, in the manner of a debugger. Linux supported a plan9-alike `/proc` filesystem since early on, and `ps` was implemented as a simple *non-setuid* program which was just opening and reading files like `/proc/<pid>/stat` and `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. Since those were meant both as the regular kernel/user interface for obtaining that info, and as a shell-friendly alternative to parsing the output of `ps` (yuck), they could not be and it made no sense to be more restrictive than `ps`.

> Sure, it would affect other users running `ps` and `htop` and the like - but that's a good thing, right? That would be the point of not making it world-readable.

No it's not a good thing. Besides breaking the standard (see the link above) that will make the system un-debuggable without root privileges, and the security advantages of that would be at best illusory. (Notice that at the time where Unix was invented, security through obscurity and free speech restrictions weren't yet as fashionable as they are today.)

You don't have to imagine what such a Linux system would look like -- there's already Android which a non-rooted system is a nasty black box (locked down in all possible ways, not just with `hidepid`) for its actual user(s), yet in no way more robust against external attackers and data collectors than a typical Debian or Slackware desktop or server.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130651/discussion-on-answer-by-user497439-is-there-any-reason-why-proc-cmdline-is-wo).

Comment: @JeffSchaller For some reason, I don't seem to have access to that chatroom link, and I would like to browse it.  Any suggestions for those of us in this situation?

Comment: @jrw32982 that chat room became inactive and was deleted automatically (about 18 hours ago as I write this).

Comment: Thanks for that update, @JeffSchaller.  Not sure why the chat can't be permanent. :-(  I was interested on more discussion about the nasty Android black box from user497439

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who want to prevent a user from seeing root user's command line:

mount the /proc file system using the hidepid=1 option:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=1 /proc
```

See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html, search hidepid.

The hidepid parameter value accepts three values:

- `0`: This is the default. Every user can read all world-readable files stored in a process directory.
- `1`: Root process directories remain listed in /proc but are not accessible to users. Users can access only their own process directories. This protects sensitive files like cmdline, sched, or status from access by non-root users. This setting does not affect the actual file permissions.
- `2`: Process files are invisible to non-root users. The existence of a process can be learned by other means, but its effective user ID (UID) and group ID (GID) are hidden.